# Access SMS mobile application

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, gwt, titanium

I am devloping a mobile app that access SMS I know if its doable in andriod if I am using GWT and in Iphone if I am using objective c. My Question is I want to use some framework that genrates native apps (for iOS and andriod) like titanium appaccerator jQuery Mobile ... etc
can some one tell me if I can access SMS on the mobile devices from the app wrttien using such tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS you cannot access the user's SMS data from an app (at least not without jailbreaking) no matter what tool you use to create it.  You can use the [MFMessageComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) to compose an SMS, but the user needs to interact with the view to actually send it - you cannot send an SMS without user interaction.

I can't help with Android I'm afraid.